# I'm banned from asking questions, could you give me some advice?

Tags: support, post-ban

I'm always trying edit to make my questions better, but it seems it's not working so well.

Could you give me some advice on how I can improve my questions?

...

Well, I'm banned again, help...

I've delete some of my poor questions.

Comment: Given the peer pressure badge you have, I'm guessing you still have a deleted post?  Any idea how many?

Comment: Considering how the OP asked here (instead of complaining), I just upvoted a question to help.

Comment: I don't think there's anything helpful about charity upvotes @ColeJohnson. How about you try editing the OP's questions instead?

Comment: @Yannis because some are completely off topic and can't be saved.

Comment: Don't forget to use the question *preview*, make sure the initial question is already great to prevent getting a quick few downvotes.

Comment: Looks like you were right on the edge - it's gone. Tread carefully though.

Comment: @Jeroen well I'm banned again... how to do the next?

Comment: @HyperGroups did you read the link??? You are not supposed to delete your questions.

Comment: *"I've delete some of my poor question."* ... you should not have done that. That is explicitly something that will push you deeper into a ban.

Comment: **Improve** bad content, don't delete it

Comment: @Bart Oh, god...

Comment: @HyperGroups Yeah, I think first things first, do what you should have done last time, read the duplicate link from beginning to end. If anythings unclear then ask

Comment: It's safe to delete one or two bad questions, but only when one have many positive score ones and some 0-score ones. If I remember correctly, I have about 3 deleted ones on Drupal Answers, and 37 non-deleted ones, from 0 to 8 points each. That should gave you a rough measurement of how safe numbers should look like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a lot of resources available on asking questions.

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [Suggestions for asking a question on help forums](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375)

If you're bouncing back and forth between being banned and unbanned, then don't rush to ask a new question the moment you're unbanned.  You're still close to the borderline at that point.  Keep improving your old questions, and *don't* post a new question unless it fits the guidelines in the resources above.  It will just get downvoted and you'll be digging yourself out of a ban again.  Edit your questions into shape *before* you post them.

Answer (score 12):

Some questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514817/how-can-i-exit-the-clcs-input-mode-of-clc-on-windows-gitshell), can't be improved. It's off topic and no matter what it will be.

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530992/how-can-i-make-the-words-become-a-pop-up-image) simply need some explanation. It shouldn't be necessary to follow a link just to know what do you want. Make text an image? What do you mean? You want to emulate title property, but with image inside? If so, say so. Show that you know the basics of what you are doing.

Listen to people who tries to help you. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680790/how-can-i-make-my-image-in-my-page-become-original-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690686/how-to-render-html-source-code-inside-a-html-document) - you was told how to fix your questions and make them good, but you chooses to ignore advices. Don't ignore others.

Comment: FYI, I've given the second example a bit of a go to demonstrate some things you could have done @hypergroups. Still not a perfect question, but perhaps a bit better and more self-contained.

Comment: @Bart yea, now it's better. I hope OP will see the difference.

Comment: Also, HyperGroups, assuming others also edited some of your posts like @Bart did, make sure to learn from the differences in the Responses tab on [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2226290/hypergroups?tab=responses&sort=revisions).

Comment: @Arjan well I'm banned again... how to do the next?

Comment: @Bart well I'm banned again... how to do the next?

Comment: *"The same procedure as every year, James!"*

Comment: @HyperGroups 1) give yourself a week or two off. 2) re-read everything we posted here, and every comment you got. Assume people want to help you even if they seems to be harsh and not nice. 3) Edit your questions to make them good. 5) Think before posting.

Comment: @HyperGroups like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680790/how-can-i-make-my-image-in-my-page-become-original-size) just yesterday you got a comment telling you how to repair your question. Why have you ignored it?! And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690686/how-to-render-html-source-code-inside-a-html-document) you ignored comments 9 hours ago...

Comment: @Mołot what was point `4)`? :P

Comment: @JonClements my bad. To tired to count properly :P To late to fix it now.

Comment: Point 4 is reading everything carefully so you notice there's no point 4 @JonClements. You passed.

Comment: @Bart you made my day :D

Comment: @Bart oh the irony if I now go and fail a simple review audit...

Answer (score 2):

I think when it comes to asking a good question, it's always good to think back to the Five W's and H, which you may or may not have heard of before.

**What** - What are you trying to do and what's happening? What's supposed to happen?

**Who** - Who does it affect? (e.g problem may occur on client PC only, but works fine for you)

**When** - When does the problem happen? (e.g Only when you run X after doing Y )

**Where** - In what environment does it happen on? (e.g Win 8, but works fine on Win 7 and below)

**Why & How** - This is the answerer's main responsibility, but you can always provide information about why you think it's happening because it shows us that you're thinking and have tried to solve it yourself.

Add on to this your research/code and you should be good to go. When you have all this info, it gives us the ability to understand your whole situation and potentially reproduce the problem. Makes life easier for answerers and gets you quicker answers!